# How to apply count() on all variables using a map/apply functions family in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, dictionary, apply, tibble

I am trying to create a user defined function to display frequency count in each variable of a dataframe.

**df**

```
dummy_df <- data.frame(gender_vector = c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male"),
                          color_vector = c('blue', 'red', 'green', 'white', 'black')
) 

dummy_df

  gender_vector color_vector
1          Male         blue
2        Female          red
3        Female        green
4          Male        white
5          Male        black
```

running count on single variable:

```
dummy_df %>%
    count(gender_vector) %>%
    as.tibble() %>% 
    
    ggplot(aes(x = n, y = gender_vector, fill = gender_vector)) +
    geom_col(show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

**Issue:** But when I create a function using this then it creates an issue:

```
var_freq_plot_fn <- function(df, selected_var){
  df %>% 
    select_if(is.character) %>%
    count(selected_var) %>%
    as.tibble() %>% 
    
    ggplot(aes(x = n, y = selected_var, fill = selected_var)) +
    geom_col() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
}
```

```
map(dummy_df, var_freq_plot_fn)
```

**Error:** `Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "character"`.

I thought by using `tibble` instead of `dataframe` will solve this but I was wrong.

I am still not clear why in `r` `datatypes` creates an issue when things are put in a `function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are different when they are in function especially when you are referring them by name and not by value. Try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

var_freq_plot_fn <- function(df, selected_var){
  df %>% 
    count(.data[[selected_var]]) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = n, y = .data[[selected_var]], fill = .data[[selected_var]])) +
    geom_col() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
}

plot_list <- purrr::map(names(dummy_df), var_freq_plot_fn, df = dummy_df)
```

---

Another way to write the function :

```
var_freq_plot_fn <- function(df){
  purrr::map(df %>% select_if(is.character) %>% names, ~
  df %>% 
    count(.data[[.x]]) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = n, y = .data[[.x]], fill = .data[[.x]])) +
    geom_col() +
    theme(legend.position = "none"))
}

var_freq_plot_fn(dummy_df)
```

Comment: thanks @Ronak for helping me out. I agree with you but from user perspective somethings are done in more complicated ways in r than in python, specially when writing functions.

Comment: And if I am trying to add a condition to select `character` vars then it doesnt work" 

`df %>% 
    select_if(is.character) %>%
    count(.data[[selected_var]]) %>%`. 

How can I add `select_if(is.character)` in the function to above code ?

Comment: You need to select the columns outside the function. `plot_list <- purrr::map(dummy_df %>% select_if(is.character) %>% names, var_freq_plot_fn, df = dummy_df)`

Comment: But this is strange from `function` writing concepts point of view as I still have to repeat the code of selecting `character` vars for each `dataframe` instead of selecting within the `function`

Comment: I don't find it strange especially when you are passing `selected_var` as an argument to the function which is specifying the column you want to count. You can also take `map` inside the function and pass entire dataframe to the function. See updated answer.

Comment: yes the **updated section** makes more sense now as in `counting frequency` it is more realistic to apply such function on `categorical variables` instead of `numerical`. Thank you for helping me out in understanding all of this.